# Exponential Distribution - serving time of customer

Tags: probability-distributions

A post office has 2 clerks. Ashima enters the post office while 2 other customers are being served by the clerks. She is next in line. Assume that the time a clerk spends serving a customer is Expo.(`lamda).

What is the probability that she will be the last of the 3 customers to be done being served?

Answer (score -1):

Since the exponential waiting time model is memory less, when the first of the two current customers has been served the distribution of waiting time till the other is finished is still $\sim Expo(\lambda)$, but so is Ashima's service time. So you are now being asked the probability that Ashima finishes after the other customer where the time to finish for both have an identical distribution and are independent...